# Looping through objects within an array, taking total of integer values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, parsefloat

I am trying to loop through objects within an array, adding all values with the key 'price'.

```
var basket = [
    {
        price: "25.00",
        id: "Hat"
    }, {
        price: "50.00",
        id: "Jacket"
    }
]

/*objects within array. purpose = able to use a for loop using .length as follows*/

function test() {
    for(var i = 0; i < basket.length; i++){
        totalPrice = 0;
        alert(itemPrice);
        itemNum = basket[i];
        itemPrice = parseFloat(itemNum.price);
        totalPrice += itemPrice;
    }
    alert(totalPrice);
}
```

My `itemPrice` alert shows that the loop runs through both objects, flashing 25 then 50. Why is my `totalPrice` variable only storing the second price, 50? The operator `+=` should be the same as `totalPrice = totalPrice + itemPrice`? Any explanation as well as fixes would be very much appreciated, trying to get a good understanding!

Comment: Because you set totalPrice to 0 in the loop. You should do it before the loop.

Comment: Or you could just use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce): `var totalPrice = basket.reduce(function(pr, cur) { return pr + parseFloat(cur.price); }, 0);` (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XqU5P/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you enter the loop, you set `totalPrice` to 0. Then you add the first item price, so totalPrice is 25. Then you enter the loop for the second time, set `totalPrice` to 0 again, 0 + 50 = 50.

You should initialize `totalPrice` before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

use reduce:

```
basket.reduce( function( previousValue, currentValue ){
           return previousValue += parseInt(currentValue.price) 
 }, 0);
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/ysJS8/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce